# Illustrator - Compund Paths (2 paths) to SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have two compound paths that seemingly can't be merged together with any of the Pathfinder presets without loss or distortion to the objects.

This image represents the two objects in the Layers panel that have been joined into Compund Path's.

[image]

Currently I'm exporting the glyph to SVG by clicking File > Save As, then using the following export settings:

[image]

The first Compound Path's path's are simply single line path's with a `100 pt` stroke applied. 
The second Compound Path's path's are 7 circles with a `#000` fill.

I've also tried probably 10-12 different approaches in converting these objects into Compound Path's before exporting to modify what is being exported to SVG, such as combining all into one Compund Path. But when I import the glyph into [IcoMoon App](https://icomoon.io/app/) the SINGLE LINE PATH's that have the `100 pt` stroke applied DO NOT RENDER.

(What I mean by a Single Line Path is simply a Path that does not close (no fill can be applied).)

**Question:**

What do we need to do to get a Single Line Path to render when loading into [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Directly from the documentation](https://icomoon.io/#docs/importing):

"Strokes get ignored by the app. You can convert them to fills."

Typically if you're doing any work with glyphs you will want to export as simple a shape as possible. The fewer overlapping shapes and extra points, the easier it will be for a program to render it as you expect.

This is especially true when using something like an online font-generator where you don't know how it will operate internally.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I didn't see that "strokes get ignored in the app" in the documentation. But I did know that we need simplify our export best we can. That is exactly my question (notice the first sentence in the question), how can we convert those strokes into fills and appropriately join the objects (to simplify the object to a Compound Path).

Comment: You'll need to outline the strokes using `Object > Expand... > Strokes`, then optionally merge all of your fills together with `Pathfinder > Unite`.